# How to avoid form data from being posted when jquery post method is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery post method to post a data that I get from the server.

I create an object with the data that I got from the server and sent this object inside the jquery post method,

Now I'm getting an error message saying unsupported media type,

The object that I created is not being sent, but the data is being sent as form data

How should I avoid this formdata being sent and send the object that I have created

Take a look at the code that I have written so far :

```js
var submitLeadDetails = function(){
    console.log('Post function executed');
    var LeadDetailsObject = {};
    LeadDetailsObject.schoolName = document.getElementById('name').value;
    LeadDetailsObject.contactPerson = document.getElementById('contact').value;
    LeadDetailsObject.contactPersonPhoneNumber =document.getElementById('phone').value;
    LeadDetailsObject.date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    LeadDetailsObject.time = document.getElementById('time').value;
    console.log(LeadDetailsObject);
 
     $.post('http://localhost:8000/webapi/leads',  LeadDetailsObject, 'json')
         .done(function(data){
         console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);
         $('#leadDetailsForm')[0].reset();
         })
         .fail(function(xhr,status,error){
             console.log(LeadDetailsObject);
             console.log(error);
         })
}
```

```html
<form id="leadDetailsForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();submitLeadDetails();">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">School Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter School Name" name="name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact">Contact Person:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Enter Contact Person Name" name="Contact" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Contact Person's Phone Number" name="phone" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                    <!--<label for="address">Address:</label>-->
                    <!--<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter School Address" id="address" required></textarea>-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Enter Date" name="date" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="time">Time:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" placeholder="Enter Time" name="Time" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"  class="btn  btn-lg pull-right" style="margin-top: 3%; background-color: #2a2c30; color:#fff;" >
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
```

As shown in the image the form data shouldn't be sent with the post method

the object that I have createed should only be sent

By returning false and by using event.preventDefault() it is just stopping the form to be refreshed.

[image]

Comment: Are you testing in Firefox? There's no global `event` object in that browser, so the event will not be prevented. I'd suggest using unobtrusive event handlers anyway, as inline are bad practice. You also have a rather odd mix of jQuery and native JS methods. I'd suggest sticking to one or the other. As you've already included jQuery in the page, you may as well make use of it's simplicity.

Comment: No, I'm testing it in chrome. Sure I will change the native JS methods and write everything in jQuery @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Read the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ -- `post` takes a `data` argument

Comment: Yes I did send data as an argument @GeorgeJempty

Comment: LeadDetailsObject is the data i'm sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your AJAX call to:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/webapi/leads',
            type: 'POST',
            data: LeadDetailsObject,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log('Success');
                console.log(data);
                $('#leadDetailsForm')[0].reset();
            },
            failure: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(LeadDetailsObject);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: will try this and let u know